# How to add custom theme to Ionic 5 application?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I need to add custom theme to Ionic 5 app. I was trying to add red-theme to variables.scss

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: red) {
  :root {
    --ion-color-primary: red;
```

And then I am trying to initialize it through index.html

```
 <meta name="color-scheme" content="red" />
```

But it's not working. I also tried to add toggle javascript code from https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced

Is it possible to theme your Ionic application by adding new primary, secondary and tertiary colors and then changing them at run time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use the **[`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)** media query for `dark` and `light` themes.

To add a new custom theme to Ionic, you simply create a new CSS class for it and overwrite every color variable under this CSS rule:

*variables.scss*

```css
body.red {
  --ion-color-primary: red;
  /*...*/
}
```

You can generate the rest of the colors with the [Color generator](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/color-generator) and the [Stepped color generator](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/themes#stepped-color-generator). Finally you might want to tweak some specific color variables such as `--ion-toolbar-background` etc., for `ios` and `md` modes, you can look at the [Default dark colors](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/dark-mode#ionic-dark-theme), copy and edit the rest of the colors from there.

After that, you can create a button which toggles the `.red` class on the body element and also store the preferred theme inside `localStorage` or use a `cookie` and toggle the class when your app loads:

*main.ts*

```js
const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme')

document.body.classList.toggle('red', theme === 'red')
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't know how to enable or toggle theme in main.ts.